# Jquery removeClass/addClass is not working

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I need to add class to elements on click and remove it, if already has a class. If I delete "removeClass" line, "addClass" work correctly.

```
$(".tagy li").click(function() {
$(this).find(":input").click();   

$(this).toggleClass('lselected');

});
```

Can you help me, what I did wrong? Thank you,
Michal

---

If I remove line with input click, toggleClass works correctly, but I need to keep it. Test: http://mbehal.cz/trat238/test/nggallery/thumbnails?f39=1&f50=1&submit=Filtrovat#1870-1920

Comment: Why not use `.toggleClass()`?

Comment: What doesn't work exactly? You didn't describe it. Provide minimal sample to replicate issue in question itself. BTW, what is the purpose of triggering click on descendant elements? Because then, you are retriggering click event on parent. So it could be your issue in fact, you remove class but because you trigger click on descendant, you add class but because you are triggering click on descendants, ...  You could try it using instead: `$(this).find(":input").triggerHandler('click');` if some jQuery click events are bound on `:input`

Comment: The problem is, that function doesn't add class to element. It just change it to <li class="">.

Testing: http://mbehal.cz/trat238/test/nggallery/thumbnails?f39=1&f50=1&submit=Filtrovat#havlickuv-brod

Comment: Ok so try using: `$(".tagy li").click(function(e){ if(e.isTrigger) return; //rest of code });`

Comment: FYI, checking your HTML markup, this is invalid, LI cannot be direct descendant of DIV element. Anyway, you have to provide minimalistic sample code in question itself, not just asking for debugging

Comment: Still the same problem. It also change it only to this: <li class="">

Comment: I edited it to actual code. I guess the problem is in input, because if I remove input click line, toggleclass works.

Comment: The problem was that you were triggering click event on descendant from parent click handler

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haha! That seems to me  use case of `event.stopPropagation()`:

```
    $(".tagy li").click(function() {
      $(this).find(":input").focus(); // may be you want to focus in the input

      $(this).toggleClass('lselected');
    });
    $(".tagy li").find(':input').on('click focus', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event to bubble up
    });
```

---

Because your input element is the children of the `li` and any event happens on the children that bubbles up to the parent. So that is causing this issue. for that you need to stop the event to bubble up with `event.stopPropagation()`.

---

```js
    $(".tagy li").click(function() {
      $(this).find(":input").focus();

      $(this).toggleClass('lselected');
    });
    $(".tagy li").find(':input').on('click focus', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation(); // stop the event to bubble up
    });
```

```css
.lselected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class='tagy'>
  <li>aasdfasfd
    <input type='text' />
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The input is a checkbox as i can see it, in fact, just need to set relevant checked property, no need of triggering click/focus event

Comment: @Jai This is HTML markup of LI but OP didn't have posted it in question itself: `<li><input name="f39" type="checkbox" value="1" checked=""><a href="#parni-lokomotivy">Parní lokomotivy</a></li>`

Comment: yeah just seen it. @A.Wolff

Answer (score 5):

Use

```
$(this).removeClass('lselected');
```

You need to specify the class name inside removeClass().

Like @josh Crozier said,You can reduce the code like this,

```
$(".tagy li").click(function() {
    $(this).find(":input").click();

    $(this).toggleClass('lselected');

});
```

Comment: `.removeClass()` will remove all classes

Comment: ...or shorter  `$(this).toggleClass('lselected').find(":input").click();`

Comment: I tried this and it still doesn't work, so I guess the problem isn't in function. If I click on "li", it changes from <li> to <li class="">.
Testing: http://mbehal.cz/trat238/test/nggallery/thumbnails?f39=1&f50=1&submit=Filtrovat#havlickuv-brod

Answer (score 1):

This is how you could fix your code:

```
$(".tagy li").click(function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('lselected')
           .find(':checkbox')
           .prop('checked', $(this).hasClass('lselected'));
});
```

But beware, you HTML markup isn't valid, LI cannot be direct child of DIV element, must be wrapped in UL.